# How do I refresh my UILabel while dismissing a view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am currently using this code below to dismiss a storyboard table view where users can make an in app purchase back to presenting an .xib which is the main view of my app and displays the total credits in a UILabel. The problem is that the new credits total which they have just added to via their purchase is not displayed in the UILabel at this point. They do show up once I completely close the app and reopen it. Is there a way to add code to my dismiss action that will refresh the .xib view or something along those lines while dismissing the current view. Thus having the new total number of credits show up in the label once the view is dismissed?? Any help would be awesome! BTW I am very new to this so in your answer please assume I don't know much!
Also I am using defaults to store the value of the credits.

```
- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender {

    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Here's how I am managing the credits/coins.

```
-(id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        coins = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"coins"] unsignedLongLongValue];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    labelCoins.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", coins];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere you have logic to add the appropriate text to the UILabel. It's probably currently in `viewDidLoad`. Put that logic in `viewWillAppear:` like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //example code to update label
    self.creditsLabel.text = numberOfCredits;
}
```

If your UILabel (creditsLabel in that example) isn't a property, it will need to be one for this to work.

---

That didn't really solve your question according to the new code you just added. All you need to do is add you `coins` assignment to `viewWillAppear`. The reason being you need to re-extract the coin value from the user defaults (this value doesn't automatically get updated when you change your value in the defaults).

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    coins = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"coins"] unsignedLongLongValue];
    labelCoins.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", coins];
}
```

Comment: I already have code for this in my viewController.m as you can see in my updated question. However I do not have my UILabel as a property, would you mind expanding on that? I'm very new so if you could go step by step that would be coo.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your situation. My initial answer didn't actually help due to the way you're updating the value, so I just added the new answer onto the bottom.

Comment: @Ned, in your presented tableView, how are you updating your `coins` model data before you dismiss the viewcontroller? Are you directly updating NSUserDefaults or do you have a singleton model (like a global variable) that you update? Or are you updating the presenting viewController's `self.coins` property?

Comment: In Herbie's post, it seems as though he is updating the NSUserDefaults value in his modal view controller.

Comment: @Ned Thank you!!! That worked like a charm! Sorry for the initial question being vague, I'm still learning! So stoked right now!

Answer (score 0):

is the UILabel a part of the cell within the table view or does it appear somewhere else in your currently displayed view?

If it's the latter, then connect your UILabel to an IBOutlet and then you can do something like:

```
- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender {
    [myCreditsLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"my credits are worth $%4.2f", creditsAsFloat]];
    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

("creditsAsFloat" up there is just a float number but in this context it needs to be member of the view controller object).

Comment: Sorry I'm new, I edited my question. I have a storyboard with a table view that is being dismissed and now it is presenting a view that is done in an .xib. (I had to combine storyboards and .xib to implement an IAP tutorial). The UILabel on the .xib displays the number that is stored in a variable "coins". Once the user purchases more coins this variable increases in value and the updated variable needs to be displayed. It shows up once I close the app and reopen in but not when I transition out of the IAP table view in storyboards back to the .xib which is controlled by a viewController.

Comment: Thanks for steering me to the answer from Ned!

Answer (score 0):

`dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` is old and out of date.

The modern way is to send this to your `presentingViewController`:

```
- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

Which allows you to provide a completion block in which you can update your presenting view controller.

Alternatively you can declare a protocol for the presented view controller's delegate to conform to - which will get you fine-grained control over the whole process (I don't know what you know - if you need to know more I can expand the answer...).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm very new so I don't know much. I updated my question above hopefully it's more clear. I don't know how to use a completion block or really how to put in the code you suggested. If you could layout where the code goes and any step by step type details that would be awesome!

Comment: @Herbie999, my answer is way more complicated than you need. I suggest you follow Ned's suggestion, see how you get on with that. In fact your answer's edit suggests you have done so - did it work? If it works, tick Ned's answer as accepted.

Comment: No that was already in my code so it does not seem to update the label when dismissing the view.

Answer (score 0):

First, we may give you inaccurate advice as we can't clearly tell where the UILabel is:

- in the view being dismissed
- in the presenting view

Guess the second option makes more sense for you to ask your question.

Second, you have two options to do this:

- ugly and fast
- good and costly

### Ugly and fast

just add an observer to the NSDefaults key you use to store your credits amount in the controller that keeps the reference to your UILabel. Look in the Xcode documentation for

```
Registering for Key-Value Observing
```

or

```
addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:
```

Doing it once isn't that bad but as it's easy and fast, you can quickly get into a real mess.

### Good and costly

Use a delegate pattern to tell your presenting controller to update the UILabel's content.

You should go for the second option. You may sound overkill and boring but it will pay in the long run.

Good luck.